# SQL Server INSERT Query from 3 Tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Users` where I have 3000 records of different users
(`UserID, Username, LoginEmail, Password`)

I have another table `Roles` (`RoleID, Code, Name, Description`) where I have 20 roles in this table

I have a third table `UserRoles` (`UserRoleID, UserID, RoleID`) - this table is currently empty.

Now I want to write a query or procedure that will insert data into the `UserRoles` table based on .....

- Get each `UserID` from the `Users` table and assign him all roles from the `Roles` table

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `UserRoleID` is identity

```
insert into userRoles ( UserID, RoleID) 
select u.UserID, r.RoleID 
from user u cross join roles r
```

Comment: @MalikUsman Don't you know how to accept an useful answer? Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can use any join that generates the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of users and roles (a cross join or or an implicit join), for example:

```
insert userroles (userid, roleid)
select u.userid, r.roleid
from users u
cross join roles r
```

or using old implicit join syntax (pre ANSI SQL 92) :

```
insert userroles (userid, roleid)
select u.userid, r.roleid
from users u, roles r
```

Both queries assumes UserRoleID is an auto generated identity field, if it's not you have to generate a value for that field too using a loop or window function like ROW_NUMBER()

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39902)